# CKEditor4: the image disappear when I switch from Rich text View to source view

Tags: ckeditor

I am using the CKEditor4 module for Drupal7 and I noticed that when I am in the "Rich Text" view  and I upload an image using the Image button.
Initially the image is there, but when I switch to the "source view" and go back to the "Rich Text" view the image disappears.
The code for the image is still in the source view and the image shows up in the Live post but NOT in the "Rich Text" view.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a very weird behavior. But after hours of debugging and testing, the fix was by re-installing the latest versions of CKEditor module (at https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor ) along with the CKEditor and CKFinder programs (at http://ckeditor.com/download ). The latest versions available as of today (April 14, 2014)
I am confident that the issue of the image disappearing had nothing to do with anything I did, since I reintroduced the exact same configuration settings as I had in the old version (the old versions combo was from about 4 months ago) and I have no problems now.

Boutros.